# Reading file of binary integers in C using open() and read()

Tags: c, binary

I am trying to read a binary file containing integers in the binary form. I need to use the open() and read() functions rather than fopen() and the like.

I open my file and try to read it, but i get binary symbols in my output.

```
char buffer[sizeof(int)];
int file1;
int bytesRead;
file1 = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
    if(file1 == -1)
    {
        printf("unable to open file\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    while((bytesRead = read(file1, &buffer, sizeof(buffer))))
    {
        printf("%d\n", buffer);
    }
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you give an example of your input and output? I'm not quite sure how you could get anything other than normal digits output when using `%d` (admittedly, they might not be the digits you want but they should still always be digits).

Comment: You pass a pointer to `printf`. `buffer` should be an `int`, then the rest is fine.

Comment: For performance reasons, you should pass a bigger buffer to `read` (typically 4Kbytes or 16Kbytes) and manage *partial* reads.

Comment: Replace `&buffer` by `buffer` and you are done.

Answer (score 1):

```
Error 1: read(file1, &buffer, sizeof(buffer)
```

When you use an array, then you need not pass it address to the "read" call.

```
Correction :
read(file1, buffer, sizeof(buffer);


Error 2 :  
while((bytesRead = read(file1, &buffer, sizeof(buffer))))
Correction : 
while((bytesRead = read(file1, &buffer, sizeof(buffer))) >= 0)
```

The while loop will evaluate to true even if the read call fails, since it returns -1 on
failure which means true.
It returns 0 when there's nothing left to read, you can apply a check on that to
indicating that there's nothing more tobe read.

Comment: Yes, but OP needs an `int` buffer (strict aliasing), and then the `&` is needed. And strictly speaking, the `&` doesn't matter here, they're the same and converted to `void *` anyway.

Comment: @mafso - If there's anything incorrect in my post, I'll be happy to   
listen to corrections. Thanks.

Comment: I still think, OP wants an `int`, not a string (and `buffer` isn't a string, it's a `char` array, possibly containing 0-bytes, without a 0-terminator and can't be printed with `%s`).

Comment: I agree..but we call an array of characters as string, in C, and thats what the buffer is. Therefore if you want to print the buffer then you should use "%s" rather than using "%d", otherwise you are most likely to get unexpected answers. That's what I think.

Comment: I don't call such a thing a string, and neither does the C standard. A string is 0-terminated. But that's just a definition. The point is: There is no 0-terminator, which may lead to undefined behaviour when trying to print with `%s`. The next problem is, that this `char` array may have embedded 0-bytes, in which case too few bytes are output.

Comment: -1 for "*You should rather use "%s".*"  This isn't correct in the context of the question.

Comment: @alk - I've updated my answer.. Is there anything else I should change?

Comment: For my understanding everything starting from "*Moreover ...*" is useless in the context of answering the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

Variables should be declared with the type they are used as:

```
int buffer;
```

If you want an `int`, declare an `int`. This is an oversimplification, but this way you’re safe against strict-aliasing violations. If only this line is changed, the other code is fine.

---

The original

```
char buffer[sizeof(int)];
```

has the drawback, that it’s impossible to read it as an `int` without violating strict-aliasing<sup>*)</sup> (strict-aliasing means, you mustn’t access an object through an lvalue with a wrong type—in short, that is, different from the declared one).

The behaviour of

```
printf("%d\n", buffer);
```

is undefined, a value of type `char *` is passed to `printf` where an `int` is expected. (This line is OK if `buffer` is an `int`; and it should be declared as an `int`, since it is read as an `int`.)

If a `char` array was really what is intended, the line

```
while((bytesRead = read(file1, &buffer, sizeof(buffer))))
```

would be unusual: Arrays decay to pointers when passed to a function, there’s no need to use the address operator `&`. (But it’s needed if `buffer` is of type `int`.)

<sup>*)</sup> Not entirely impossible, you could *type-pun* with a `union`.